# Execute program in one class with Swing GUI

Tags: java, swing

I have a program that compares then merges two files and creates a new one. I am attempting to now program a GUI using Swing that can interact with this program. So far, everything appears to be in place but when I attempt to run the program I get a ton of Swing and awt errors. Below is the program I am attempting to run.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package HelloCKL;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;


public class HelloCKL {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String sourceFile1Path = helloSwingCKL.fileSource;
        String sourceFile2Path = helloSwingCKL.fileToAppend;

        String mergedFilePath = "merged_test2.ckl";

        File[] files = new File[2];
        files[0] = new File(sourceFile1Path);
        files[1] = new File(sourceFile2Path);

        File mergedFile = new File(mergedFilePath);

        mergeFiles(files, mergedFile);
    }


    public static void mergeFiles(File[] files, File mergedFile) {
        // NEW
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        FileWriter fstream = null;
        BufferedWriter out = null;
        try {
            fstream = new FileWriter(mergedFile, false);
            out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Going in a different direction. We are using a couple booleans to tell us when we want to copy or not. So at the beginning since we start
        // with our source file we set copy to true, we want to copy everything and insert vuln names into our list as we go. After that first file 
        // we set the boolean to false so that we dont start copying anything from the second file until it is a vuln. We set to true when we see vuln
        // and set it to false if we already have that in our list. 
        // We have a tmpCopy to store away the value of copy when we see a vuln, and reset it to that value when we see an </VULN>
        Boolean copy = true;
        Boolean tmpCopy = true;
        for (File f : files) {
            System.out.println("merging: " + f.getName());
            FileInputStream fis;
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

                String aLine;
                while ((aLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Skip the close checklist and we can write it in at the end
                    if (aLine.trim().equals("</CHECKLIST>")){
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (aLine.trim().equals("<VULN>")){
                        // Store our current value of copy
                        tmpCopy = copy;
                        copy = true;

                        String aLine2 = in.readLine();  
                        String aLine3 = in.readLine();
                        String nameLine = in.readLine();

                        if(list.contains(nameLine.trim())){
                            System.out.println("Skipping: " + nameLine);
                            copy = false;
//                            while (!(aLine.trim().equals("</VULN>"))){
//                                aLine = in.readLine();
//                            }
//                            continue; // this would skip the writing out to file part
                        }
                        else{
                            list.add(nameLine.trim());
                            System.out.println("::: List is now :::" );
                            System.out.println(list.toString());
                        }
                        if(copy){
                            out.write(aLine);
                            out.newLine();
                            out.write(aLine2);
                            out.newLine();
                            out.write(aLine3);
                            out.newLine();
                            out.write(nameLine);
                            out.newLine();
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        if(copy){
                          out.write(aLine);
                          out.newLine();
                        }
                    }
                    // after we have written to file, if the line was a close vuln, switch copy back to original value
                    if (aLine.trim().equals("</VULN>")){
                        copy = tmpCopy;
                    }
                }

                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            copy = false;
        }

        // Now lets add the close checklist tag we omitted before
        try{
          out.write("</CHECKLIST>");
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the Swing coding that I am working with.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package hellockl;

import static HelloCKL.HelloCKL.mergeFiles;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;


public class helloSwingCKL extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form helloSwingCKL
     */
    public helloSwingCKL() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(java.awt.Color.lightGray);

        jButton1.setText("Source");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("New .ckl");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField3.setText("Save merged file as...");

        jButton3.setText("Merge");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(jTextField3)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 75, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGap(5, 5, 5)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addComponent(jTextField1)
                                .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 250, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(92, 92, 92)
                        .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 127, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 111, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(36, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(54, 54, 54)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(7, 7, 7)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(104, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File source = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        String fileSource = source.getAbsolutePath();
        jTextField1.setText(fileSource);
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File toAppend = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        String fileToAppend = toAppend.getAbsolutePath();
        jTextField2.setText(fileToAppend);
    }                                        

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        HelloCKL.mergeFiles();
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(helloSwingCKL.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(helloSwingCKL.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(helloSwingCKL.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(helloSwingCKL.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new helloSwingCKL().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Below are the "ton of errors"...

```
*run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: hellockl.HelloCKL.main
    at hellockl.helloSwingCKL.jButton3ActionPerformed(helloSwingCKL.java:145)
    at hellockl.helloSwingCKL.access$300(helloSwingCKL.java:18)
    at hellockl.helloSwingCKL$4.actionPerformed(helloSwingCKL.java:73)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 15 seconds)*
```

And below are the compiler errors.

```
 Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\blakey\Documents\NetBeansProjects\helloCKL\build\classes
C:\Users\blakey\Documents\NetBeansProjects\helloCKL\src\hellockl\helloSwingCKL.java:3: error: package HelloCKL does not exist
import static HelloCKL.HelloCKL.mergeFiles;
C:\Users\blakey\Documents\NetBeansProjects\helloCKL\src\hellockl\helloSwingCKL.java:3: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static HelloCKL.HelloCKL.mergeFiles;
C:\Users\blakey\Documents\NetBeansProjects\helloCKL\src\hellockl\helloSwingCKL.java:129: error: cannot access HelloCKL
        HelloCKL.main();
  bad source file: C:\Users\blakey\Documents\NetBeansProjects\helloCKL\src\hellockl\HelloCKL.java
    file does not contain class hellockl.HelloCKL
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
3 errors
C:\Users\blakey\Documents\NetBeansProjects\helloCKL\nbproject\build-impl.xml:952: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\blakey\Documents\NetBeansProjects\helloCKL\nbproject\build-impl.xml:269: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Could you reduce it even further? And please, provide some short form of the input files.

Comment: @MartinZabel: most of it is NetBeans-generated code, and I doubt that the OP knows how to create a Swing application by hand yet. To the OP (original poster), I recommend that you learn to code Swing by hand before using code-generation. Otherwise you will frequently paint himself in a corner and not know how to get out. The [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info) tag has resources you'll need.

Answer (score 2):

> when I attempt to run the program I get a ton of Swing and awt errors

You look to be trying to run code that won't compile **never do that** -- first fix any and all compilation errors before trying to run a program, and if you can't figure out how to do that and need help then at least post the **compilation** errors here with your question, since "a ton of errors" doesn't tell us much that we can work with.

Your main problem on quick look of your code is that you're calling the `mergeFiles(...)` method wrong. You're calling it without passing in any parameters:

```
HelloCKL.mergeFiles();
```

and it has been written to require two parameters:

```
public static void mergeFiles(File[] files, File mergedFile) {
```

A solution: Call the method just as you try to call it in the original main method, by passing in an array of files that you wish to merge and the end result file where you want the merge to reside. It looks like you have other code that tries to get these very files, but doesn't seem to do anything with the results that it gets, and it is this with which you should work.

Comment: I've added the output to the main post.

Comment: @Ablakey: the most important statement is again that you're trying to run uncompilable code: `RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code`. Again, never do that. **Again**, show the compiler error message, not the runtime exception.

Comment: I apologize, I have now attached the compiler errors.